# uploading web.py app on Heroku

Tags: heroku, web.py

just started on using web.py and heroku, so...

I have this simple app that I want to upload to heroku and I have followed the instruction from http://joshuaoiknine.com/post/47196802362/publishing-for-the-web-py-python-framework-to-heroku

This is my Procfile:

```
web: python code.py $PATH
```

But after I uploaded it to heroku, it gives me the application error.
The heroku log shows me this:

```
2013-08-08T03:27:44.956675+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python code.py /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`
2013-08-08T03:27:45.673358+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2013-08-08T03:27:45.673358+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "code.py", line 52, in <module>
2013-08-08T03:27:45.673358+00:00 app[web.1]:     app.run()
2013-08-08T03:27:45.673358+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 313, in run
2013-08-08T03:27:45.673358+00:00 app[web.1]:     return wsgi.runwsgi(self.wsgifunc(*middleware))
2013-08-08T03:27:45.673358+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/wsgi.py", line 54, in runwsgi
2013-08-08T03:27:45.673358+00:00 app[web.1]:     return httpserver.runsimple(func, validip(listget(sys.argv, 1, '')))
2013-08-08T03:27:45.673358+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/net.py", line 76, in validip
2013-08-08T03:27:45.673358+00:00 app[web.1]:     port = int(port)
2013-08-08T03:27:45.673552+00:00 app[web.1]: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin'
2013-08-08T03:27:46.866238+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-08T03:27:46.881655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

However, when i tried the second method, I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 55, in <module>
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'host'
```

Any ideas how to get my app onto heroku up and running?

Comment: code.py expects an integer argument first, not your $PATH. Change your `Procfile`. I am not sure why you would want to even pass $PATH to your code.

Comment: sorry, I am not sure what to change it to, because when I put 8080 and upload it, it also gives me error :(

Comment: Can you: (1) paste your `web.py` (2) change to `$PORT` and paste the error if not.

Comment: Yeah! Changing it to `$PORT` works. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @NitzanShaked Hey, nice work :) You should post your comment(s) as an answer so you can be upvoted and accepted :)

Comment: Here is another recent [howto blog entry](http://www.hakanu.net/2014/09/29/deploy-web-py-jinja2-application-with-pip-requirements-on-heroku/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`code.py` expects an integer argument first, not your $PATH. It is probably a port it is expecting, so instead of `$PATH` in your `Procfile` pass `$PORT`.

Even better: change your code to use `ENV["PORT"]` and if that's not defined (as might be the case in your local dev env) then a default (say, 8000 or 8080 for your dev env).

On Heroku, the port your server needs to listen on is not fixed -- it changes with every restart of every dyno. Heroku will set the environment variable `PORT` to let you know which port to listen on.